# How to call Java function with int parameter from JNI

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have a static Java function in an Activity. This function has int parameter. I want to call this function from JNI. I use below code to call, but I don't know how to pass int parameter:

In Java:

```
public static void updateTopScoreLeaderboard(int score) {
    Log.i("", "updateTopScoreLeaderboard " + score);
}
```

In JNI:

```
if (JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "com/nch/myApp/MyActivity", "updateTopScoreLeaderboard", "()V"))
{
    methodInfo.env->CallStaticObjectMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID);
}
methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);
```

That code work well if Java function has no param. But in this case (has int param), it not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the method signature to match the int parameter, so it's `(I)V` instead of `()V`, and also add your int parameter to the method invocation:

```
int myInt = 0;

if (JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "com/nch/myApp/MyActivity", "updateTopScoreLeaderboard", "(I)V"))
{
    methodInfo.env->CallStaticObjectMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID, myInt );
}
methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);
```

Comment: @huync To find signatures use `javap`. For example, `javap -s -public com/nch/myApp/MyActivity | egrep -A 2 "updateTopScoreLeaderboard"`. Just as in running `java`, the code needs to be compiled first and be sure to pass in a classpath if needed.

Comment: That is a great answer.

Comment: You should call `CallStaticVoidMethod`, instead of `CallStaticObjectMethod`, since the Java method returns `void`, and not an object.